# Spring simply rendering an html page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**The problem:**

Using Spring 4, I am getting this when visiting a webpage

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Aug 15 16:41:29 BST 2014
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

**What I have:**

I have this Main class:

```java
// src/main/java/abc/Main.java
package abc;

import abc.web.WebAppConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebAppConfig.class);

    }
}
```

Then I have this WebAppConfig.class (currently with just some configuration annotations):

```java
// src/main/java/abc/web/WebAppConfig.java
package abc.web;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebAppConfig {

}
```

And this controller HomeController.java:

```java
// src/main/java/abc/web/HomeController.java
package abc.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("HELLO !!");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

The HELLO !! shows up in the logs.

And finally I have a html file at `src/main/java/abc/webapp/home.html`, with just some html tags including a `p` tag with `Hello, world!`.

**The question:**

I understand that I am missing the way of rendering the view, but I searched a couple of questions on stackoverflow and haven't find a solution yet.

Can someone explain how can I get Spring to render a webpage ? What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post the server logs from the request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Boot will automatically use and configure Thymeleaf as the view rendering engine, as long as it's on the classpath.
To put it on the classpath use

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```

in the gradle build file.

If you are using maven add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In your case in order to display the `home.html` view (in accordance to the controller you are using), you need to place it under `/resources/templates`.

For a complete example, check out [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) guide.

Comment: Can you please tell what should I do for maven explicitly?

Comment: Use `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Comment: @TejeshRaut Alternatively, you can go to http://start.spring.io/ and download a generated package to see what's needed in the maven file.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest answer to the "how can I get Spring Boot to render a webpage?" question is: place your home.html file inside `src/main/resources/static/` folder. The page will be available under the `/home.html` URL.

More details [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

Comment: When to put the HTML files under subdirectory "static" and when under "templates"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably not configured template engine and view resolver. See example with thymeleaf here http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html
As thymeleaf template is a valid HTML code and vice verse you can use it.